# To remove extra dependencies inherited from spring-boot-starter-parent

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
```

When spring-boot-starter-parent is used as parent, then it includes many unnecessary dependencies. Like in my case it fetches the dependencies for 
(spring-mobile-device , spring-social-facebook , spring-social-linkedin , org.apache.activemq ) which i don't want.

If I open my effective POM(with get's auto created) , it's contains hell lot of dependencies which i don't want.

Is there any way to remove the unnecessary dependencies which are not used in the project? Is there a tool to identify such dependencies?

Any help is appreciated :)

Thanks

POM.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>demo</groupId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>demo</description>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId> <artifactId>gson</artifactId> 
        <version>2.2.4</version>$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ </dependency> -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId> <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId> 
        <version>1.17.1</version> </dependency> -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId> <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId> 
        <version>4.4.1</version>$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId> 
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId> <version>4.4.1</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>joda-time</groupId> <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId> 
        <version>2.8</version> </dependency> -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId> <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId> 
        <version>3.5.4</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>demo.Application</start-class>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<artifactId>DEMO</artifactId>
```

Comment: The partent you have choosen does only a `dependencyManagement` so you can't inherit really dependencies. If you like using dependencies they must be defined by a list of `dependencies`...Can you please show your pom file?

Comment: thanks for reply khmarbaise.

Comment: If you don't want the extra dependencies that the archetype depends on then don't use the archetype.

Comment: i have added pom.xml. if you look at pom, there is nowhere mention of ((spring-mobile-device , spring-social-facebook , spring-social-linkedin , org.apache.activemq ), but the auto generated Effective pom is showing these entries. One more thing , if I check for jars which get downloaded after maven build, I don't see any jars related to  spring-mobile-device , spring-social-facebook , spring-social-linkedin , org.apache.activemq . Why is that so ?

Answer (score 2):

`spring-boot-starter-parent` doesn't declare any dependencies. However, via `spring-boot-dependencies`, it does provide dependency management for a wide-range of *potential* dependencies.

From [Maven's documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management):

> The dependency management section is a mechanism for centralizing dependency information. When you have a set of projects that inherits a common parent it's possible to put all information about the dependency in the common POM and have simpler references to the artifacts in the child POMs

The references to artifacts can be simpler as, thanks to the dependency management, there's no need to declare a version. For example:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <dependency>
<dependencies>
```

If you don't specify a version, Maven will use the version that's configured in the dependency management.

Only when you add an entry in your pom's `<dependencies>` section will your project actually have that dependency and Maven will download it as part of the build.